# Is there AVPlayer's 'frameChanged' callback?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avplayer

I want to do smth at frame changing with AVPlayer's calayer.
Can I do this with AVPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at *readyForDisplay* in **AVPlayerLayer** (which you would normally add your **AVPlayer** into this CALayer by *playerLayerWithPlayer*).

Comment: The readyForDisplay corresponds only to the first frame, the question is about a callback on each frame.